# Not redirecting to next page

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have recorded the script in selenium ide and it is working fine with it.
I have a login form, after successful login it should redirect to dashboard.
But when I run through Selenium RC it is not redirecting to dashboard after clickAndWait. Chrome says Page is not available but when I reload the page it is working. Help Me.

Selenium RC: selenium-server-standalone-2.34.0
Selenium version: Selenium IDE 2.2.0
OS:Windows 7
Browser:Firefox, Chrome
Browser version: Firefox 23

Code:

```
<tr> <td>setSpeed</td> <td>1000</td> <td></td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>open</td> <td>login.aboutone.com/</td>; <td></td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>waitForPageToLoad</td> <td>50000</td> <td></td> </tr> <tr> <td>waitForElementPresent</td> <td>id=login_form</td> <td></td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>type</td> <td>id=UserName</td> <td>uitest+aotest13763045730@abc.com</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>clickAndWait</td> <td>css=input.btn.primary</td> <td></td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>type</td> <td>id=Password</td> <td>xyx$</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>clickAndWait</td> <td>css=input.btn.primary</td> <td></td> </tr>
```

Comment: How can we know if you don't show codes?

Comment: <tr>
 <td>setSpeed</td>
 <td>1000</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>https://login.aboutone.com/</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
 <td>50000</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>id=login_form</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=UserName</td>
 <td>uitest+aotest13763045730@abc.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>css=input.btn.primary</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=Password</td>
 <td>xyx$</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>css=input.btn.primary</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: Above is recorded HTML code. After success it should redirect to Dashboard.

Comment: Are you sure you want a click after typing in the username AND a click after typing in the password?  Seems like you'd have 2 login attempts, each with half the required information.

Comment: On a side note, you can run your HTML against a web driver protocol and not the selenium RC server with this project: https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java  This will make steps like setSpeed and captureEntirePageScreenshot available.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

1. Remove waitForPageToLoad from the test - open command automatically waits.
2. Remove the first clickAndWait command.
3. Remove the setSpeed command - it is not yet implemented.